# What is software requirement to run a docker image on a target machine?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I need to know what software is required for a machine to run a docker image. E.g., if I want to deploy and run a docker container on a machine X. What is minimum required software to be installed (e.g., docker daemon is sufficient or more is required?)
In my understanding, Machine X needs to be able to connect to Docker registry and there should be runtime environment for docker image to run. But I could not find anywhere minimum requirements to run a docker container on a machine.

I am NOT interested in system HARDWARE requirements.

Edit [24-Nov-2020]: I am looking for windows container deployment

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to run is Docker containers, then just the Docker engine and its supporting packages which can be found in the 'installation' section in the Docker documentation will suffice:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/

Comment: Thank you @Sergio for the link. I am looking for the same for windows container. Is there a way to separately install docker engine for windows?

Comment: For Windows, you'll be able to follow the Microsoft guide to install and run containers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/set-up-environment?tabs=Windows-Server